# Unable to replace the file contents

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to replace the contents of file using perl command in another shell script:

Filename: INFA.param

Contents:

```
$ParamUser=SOMEUSERNAME
$ParamPswd=SOMEPASSWORD
$$StartTime=2021-06-26 08:31:51:1195079
$$EndTime=2021-06-26 09:31:51:1195079
```

When I open the above file in another shell script "pp.sh"

```
cat INFA.param > temp.param
. ./temp.param
pmcmdpassword=$(pmcmd $password -e CRYPTDATA)
perl -pe -e "s#ParamPswd=\Q$ParamPswd\E#ParamPswd=$pmcmdpassword#g" INFA.param
```

I am getting some errors:

```
=SOMEUSERNAME: not found
=SOMEPASSWORD: not found
31850942StartTime=2021-06-26 08:31:51:1195079: not found
31850942EndTime=2021-06-26 09:31:51:1195079: not found
```

Could you please suggest me how I should replace the password.

Comment: In shell, you use `$` to *get* the value of a variable, not to *set* it. Also, if you're assigning a string that contains spaces, quote it. Finally, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend (although on some of these, it'll have a hard time figuring out what you intended).

Comment: Thank You @GordonDavisson - I have to replace the $ParamPswd='SOMEVALUE1' by another $ParamPswd='SOMEVALUE2', Is there any way you suggest?

Comment: I do not understand. You want a perl command to remove `$` from file? How is this related to bash? `$ has the special meaning in shell script, so getting the above error. Could you please suggest me how I should replace the password` Don't you want to fix the error first? Or you do not care about the error, it's completely unrelated, and you are asking only how to replace the string `SOMEPASSWORD` in a file by another value specifically using perl? Why do you mention the error if you want to replace something in a file?

Comment: Thank You @KamilCuk I have to fix the issue by replacing the password by another value.

Comment: Replacing the string `SOMEPASSWORD` by another value is unrelated to the bash assignment error caused by leading `$` in variable assignments. I do not understand, I'll run away.

Comment: I have edited the question, could you please help me how to replace the password now. @KamilCuk

Comment: Assuming that code will need the same quoting -- even if you've dealt with the leading `$` difference -- to be parsed by both perl and shell is... not a safe assumption to be making, _especially_ when that code contains arbitrary user-provided strings like passwords. I'd _really_ suggest switching to a common format like JSON.

Comment: But if you're not going to do that, at least explain _why_ you're trying to read `INFA.param` into bash when none of your bash code even tries to refer to any of the variables it contains.

Comment: Besides other improvements, first see the difference when you remove all `$` characters from `INFA.param`. After that read the above comments again.

Answer (score 1):

You can only safely use `.` or `source` when a file was written to be valid shell source code. That is not true of the file you have here: shell assignments don't start with `$`.

If you're trying to modify the existing password by reencrypting it, and that's why your code tries to read the original file into the shell interpreter, then you might want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT sh, ONLY bash

declare -A variables=( )
while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
  variables[$key]=$value
done < INFA.param

oldPassword=${variables['$ParamPswd']}
newPassword=$(pmcmd "$oldPassword" -e CRYPTDATA)

in="$oldPassword" out="$newPassword" \
  perl -pi -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g' INFA.param
```

It's even easier if your new password is input; then you don't need to read the original file at all in the first place:

```
newPassword=$(pmcmd "${password?Password undefined}" -e CRYPTDATA)

out="$newPassword" \
  perl -pi -e 's/^[$]ParamPswd=.*$/$ENV{"out"}/g' INFA.param
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the following as `bash` script:

```
$ParamUser=SOMEUSERNAME
$ParamPswd=SOMEPASSWORD
$$StartTime=2021-06-26 08:31:51:1195079
$$EndTime=2021-06-26 09:31:51:1195079
```

Unlike Perl, bash uses the `$` only to expand variables. For example:

```
a='some text'
echo "$a"
```

gives in bash:

```
some text
```

When your script starts, the bash variable `ParamUser` is empty, so the line `$ParamUser=SOMEUSERNAME` will be expanded to `=SOMEUSERNAME`. That is not a valid command, and therefore bash complains

```
=SOMEUSERNAME: not found
```

For bash

```
$$StartTime=2021-06-26 08:31:51:1195079
```

contains multiple different problems, among which the spacing. Also, `$$` expands to the PID of your current process, which is 31850942, apparently.

So, a solution would be

```
ParamUser=$(sed -n 's/ParamUser=//p' INFA.param)
```

(same for the rest)

Note that the line

```
pmcmdpassword=$(pmcmd $password -e CRYPTDATA)
```

uses a variable `password` that is not set in the script-part in the question.